# Get incoming number from a Linphone call

Tags: iphone, swift, voip, linphone, incoming-call

I am trying to detect the number that is calling me during a Linphone call. I have tried

```
case LinphoneCallConnected:
            NSLog("callStateChanged: LinphoneCallConnected")
            NSLog("CALL ID: \(linphone_call_log_get_call_id(linphone_call_get_call_log(linphone_core_get_current_call(lc)))!)")
```

but that is null. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

in my app I take `linphoneCore` and `linphoneCall` and after call `linphone_call_get_remote_address`. Now you have `linphoneAddress` from which you can extract username `linphone_address_get_username`.

Full code here:

```
- (NSString *)userNameFromCurrentCall {

    LinphoneCore *lc = [LinphoneManager getLc];
    LinphoneCall *currentcall = linphone_core_get_current_call(lc);

    if (currentcall != NULL) {
        LinphoneAddress const * addr = linphone_call_get_remote_address(currentcall);

        if (addr != NULL) {
            return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:linphone_address_get_username(addr)];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SString *)userNameFromCurrentCall {

```
LinphoneCore *lc = [LinphoneManager getLc];
LinphoneCall *currentcall = linphone_core_get_current_call(lc);

if (currentcall != NULL) {
    LinphoneAddress const * addr = linphone_call_get_remote_address(currentcall);

    if (addr != NULL) {
        return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:linphone_address_get_username(addr)];
    }
}

return nil;
```